# Parallelize pyspark 2.2.0 dataframe partitioned write to S3

Tags: dataframe, amazon-s3, parallel-processing, pyspark

Starting to work with pyspark and run into a bottleneck I have created with my code:

I'm "grouping by" pyspark 2.2.0 dataframe into partitions by drive_id
and writing each partition (group) into its own location on S3.

I need it to define Athena table on S3 location partitioned by drive_id - this allows me to read data very efficiently if queried by drive_id.

```
        #df is spark dataframe 
        g=df.groupBy(df.drive_id)
        rows=sorted(g.count().collect())
        #each row is a parition
        for row in rows:
            w=df.where((col("drive_id") == row.drive_id))
        w.write.mode('append').parquet("s3n://s3bucket/parquet/drives/"+str(table)+"/drive_id="+str(row.drive_id) )
```

The problem is that the loop makes processing serial and writes drive partitions only one by one.

Obviously this doesn't scale well because single partition write task is quite small and parallelizing it doesn't give much.

How do I replace the loop with single write command that will write all partitions into different locations ins a single operation?

This operation should parallelize to run on spark workers, not driver.

Answer (score 4):

I figured out the answer - surprisingly simple.

dataframe.write.parquet has optional parameter partitionBy(names_of_partitioning_columns).

So no need in the "group by" and no need in the loop:
using the single line:

```
df.write.partitionBy(drive_id).parquet("s3n://s3bucket/dir")
```

creates partitions in standard hive format "s3n://s3bucket/dir/drive_id=123"